# How to enable Safe Haskell for a module in a backwards compatible way

Tags: haskell, backwards-compatibility, cabal

Suppose you have a module that you know is safe.

You want to mark it as Safe Haskell with something like `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}` in the module itself or with something like `Extensions: Safe` in the cabal file.  Unfortunately, doing either of these breaks backwards compatibility (i.e. the module will not build on GHC < 7.2).

If the entire library is Safe, you can just wrap the extensions directive in the cabal file like this:

```
if impl(ghc >= 7.2)
  Extensions: Safe
```

But that only works for the entire library.

How do you mark **a single module** as Safe Haskell in a backwards compatible way?

Comment: `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}; #if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 702; {-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}; #endif` ?

Comment: ...and I was just about to submit an answer with that exact piece of code. @DanielFischer is right; it works, but it wouldn't have worked on older GHC versions IIRC because all `LANGUAGE` pragmas had to be in one block back then (so `CPP` wouldn't have had been enabled "in time" for the following line). You can also define a Cabal flag that detects the GHC version and conditionally uses a completely different file when compiling.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  I'll accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: @dflemstr Do you happen to remember which GHC versions had that behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to support GHC versions older than 6.12 (6.12.3 is the oldest I have tested the construct with¹), you can do it with the preprocessor,

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 702
{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}
#endif
```

Alternatively, you can use a flag in the `.cabal` file to select the source file which to include.

¹ For ghc-6.12, you must have all `{-# LANGUAGE #-}` pragmas not guarded by the `#if` in one group before the `#if`, since 7.0, they may also appear after the `#if`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write two versions of the module, and choose between them at compile-time. For example:

```
-- has-safe/Foo.hs
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
foo = 3

-- no-safe/Foo.hs
{-# LANGUAGE CPP, Safe #-}
foo = 3

-- foo.cabal
if impl(ghc >= 7)
    hs-source-dirs: has-safe
else
    hs-source-dirs: no-safe
```

There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach over the `CPP`-based approach. The main advantage is that you have all the conditions cabal supports available to you to make your choice. The main disadvantage is that you now have two files to keep in sync. (However, this should be particularly easy to automate: something like

```
echo {-# LANGUAGE Safe #-} > has-safe/Foo.hs
cat no-safe/Foo.hs >> has-safe/Foo.hs
```

after each edit to `no-safe/Foo.hs` should do the trick and can be automated in various ways.)